# Why is Lua's arg table not one-indexed?

Tags: lua

In the Lua command line, when I pass arguments to a script like this:

```
lua myscript.lua a b c d
```

I can read the name of my script and arguments from the global `arg` table. arg[0] contains the script name, arg[1] - arg[#arg] contain the remaining arguments. What's odd about this is table is that it has a value at index 0, unlike every other Lua array which starts indexing at 1. This means that when iterating over it like this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(arg) do print(i, v) end
```

the output only considers index 1-4, and does not print the script name. Also `#arg` evaluates to 4, not 5.

Is there any good reason for this decision? It initially took me aback, and I had to verify that the manual wasn't mistaken.

Comment: One could argue that the script name is not an argument _to the script_.

Comment: "Lua array which starts indexing at 1": _Array_ is not a Lua domain concept. Every Lua table _sequence_ starts indexing at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking *why* certain design decisions were made is always tricky because only the creator of the language can really answer.  I guess it was chosen such that you can iterate over the arguments using `ipairs` and don't have to handle the first one special because it's the script name and not an argument.

`#arg` is meaningless anyway because it counts only the number of elements in the consecutive array section but the zeroth and negative indices are stored in the hashmap section.  To obtain the actual number of elements use

```
local n = 0
for _ in pairs(arg) do
    n = n + 1
end
```

At least it is documented in [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html):

> A main script can retrieve its arguments in the global variable `arg`. In a call like
>
> ```
> prompt> lua script a b c
> ```
>
> lua creates the table arg with all the command-line arguments, before running the script. The script name goes into index 0; its first argument (`a` in the example), goes to index 1, and so on. Eventual options go to negative indices, as they appear before the script. For instance, in the call
>
> ```
> prompt> lua -e "sin=math.sin" script a b
> ```
>
> `lua` collects the arguments as follows:
>
> ```
> arg[-3] = "lua"
> arg[-2] = "-e"
> arg[-1] = "sin=math.sin"
> arg[0] = "script"
> arg[1] = "a"
> arg[2] = "b"
> ```
>
> More often than not, the script only uses the positive indices (`arg[1]` and `arg[2]`, in the example).

Comment: Thanks. While SO is a bad place to ask why a decision was taken, there is something that can be learned from users about why they think the decision was useful. For example, I didn't know I could get those negative-index command line arguments.

Comment: First, the array optimization does not go away. Indices 0 and less will use hashmap slots, indices 1 and up will use array slots. Second, the `#` operator doesn't care whether array slots or hashmap slots are used as long as there are no holes in the range of your integer keys >= 1. So the explicit `ipairs` loop is unnecessary, and plain `#arg` works fine for the number of arguments to the Lua script.

Comment: @siffiejoe Thank you for the clarification.  I will update my answer.

Comment: I never knew the option flags were stored in the `arg` array too, but [indeed](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.c.html#createargtable) this is (still) the case.

Answer (score 3):

`arg` in Lua mimics `argv` in C: `arg[0]` contains the name of the script just like `argv[0]` contains the name of the program.

This does not contradict 1-based arrays in Lua, since the arguments to the script are the more important data. The name of the script is seldom used.